# How to define the pdf-object for using Cordova-PDF-Generator?

Tags: cordova, pdf

I'm working on a web-app with Cordova and Ionic.
In this app i installed the Cordova-PDF-Creator for generating PDF-files out of HTML-files (exactly their content).
The Installation worked fine, but when i try to execute one of the code-examples, i get an error because i haven't defined the variable "pdf".
Does anybody who uses that plugin know how to define the variable?
Unfortunately there is no good code example for this on the page of that plugin ([Cordova-PDF-Generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-pdf-generator)).

This is the code which is called when i click a button on my test page.

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.CreatePdf = function () {
        pdf.htmlToPDF({
            url: "http://www.google.es",
            documentSize: "A4",
            landscape: "portrait",
            type: "base64"
        }, this.success, this.failure);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

declare cordova below import

> declare var cordova;

then access the pdf inside cordova like this

> cordova.plugins.pdf.fromData()